# How to use Observable inside http request Url?

Tags: angular, observable, httprequest

I am having trouble using an Observable value inside an HTTP get request.

1. First I have a service that fetches the user setting which triggers if the user is authenticated and when different settings are applied.

```typescript
        private userSettings: BehaviorSubject<UserSettingDto> = new BehaviorSubject<UserSettingDto(null);
        userSettings$ = this.userSettings.asObservable();
    
            loadUserSettings() {
            return this.http.get<any>(``).toPromise().then(
            data => {
              this.userSettings.next(data);
            });
          }
```

2. Second service that will fetch data that depends on the user setting.

```typescript
  fetchData(): Observable<ObjectType[]>{
    
        return this.UserSettingService.userSettings$.subscribe(
          settings => {
          return this.http.get<ObjectType[]>('Url' + settings); // This value must be returned of ObjectType[]
        }));
      }
```

**The main issue that I want to use `userSetting$` for the HTTP request Url and return that request** since I am subscribing from a component where I view the fetched data, I have tried several methods and haven't achieved yet the desired results such as SwitchMap.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is what you want:

```
fetchData(): Observable<ObjectType[]> {
  return this.UserSettingService.userSettings$.pipe(
    switchMap(userSettingDto =>
      this.http.get<ObjectType[]>('Url' + settings))
  );
};
```

Explanation: The `UserSettingsService` exposes an Observable `userSettings$`, which will emit a value of type `UserSettingDto` once the request performed in `UserSettingsService::loadUserSettings` is successfully completed. Calling `fetchData` will now return an `Observable` that emits when:

1. `UserSettingsService.userSettings$` has emitted a non-error value
2. `this.http.get<ObjectType[]>('Url' + settings)` has emitted a non-error value

Basically, "only perform the http call when the user settings are available". If you want to actually perform the http request, don't forget to subscribe to the Observable returned by `fetchData`.

Comment: Thanks, However userSettingDto  is null since it's value initialized on refresh or login or change setting and  fetchData also triggered on home page, so userSettingDto is null when fetchData is triggered. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

```
fetchData() {
  return this.http.get('').pipe(
    switchMap(data => {
      return this.http.get(URL + data);
    })
  );
}

const objectTypes = await Service.fetchData().toPromise();
```